# Ant design - is there a way to get styles that im actually using?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, babeljs, antd

installed recently ant design https://ant.design/

However, it doesn't use styled components, just old basic css modules. The .css file is like 10k of lines. There's a way to use only these u need, but first u have to install babel.

Unfortunately, Im not using babel in my project, just the typescript.

https://ant.design/docs/react/introduce - here is written that I need babel and babel-import-plugin. But as I said Im not using it and I dont want to use it in my project.

For those who dont want to enter external websites:

```
Use modularized antd#
Use babel-plugin-import (Recommended)

// .babelrc or babel-loader option
{
  "plugins": [
    ["import", { "libraryName": "antd", "libraryDirectory": "es", "style": "css" }] // `style: true` for less
  ]
}
```

**Question**: Is there a way to use modularized css (import only these styles that u need) using typescript or just webpack or so? Without babel?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I have been using Antd with react from past 1 year.

This is the problem when you will try to use the modularized antd otherwise this issue would not exist.

**In modularized**

import DatePicker from 'antd/lib/date-picker';  // for js

import 'antd/lib/date-picker/style/css';        // for cs

**In non modularized**

import 'antd/dist/antd.css'; //once in index.js file in src folder the

import {DataPicker,Button,Grid} from 'antd'; //whatever component you needed

Do you really wanted to user the modularized antd?

If you changed your mood here is my git repository for that https://github.com/shreyansRS/react-redux-antd

If you still wanted to use modularized, i think importing 'antd/lib/date-picker/style/css' in index.js should work.